# Service Fabric Node Balancing doesn't trigger

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I attempt to test service fabric node balancing mechanism on my own private cluster and can’t figure out why it doesn’t work. Below are the steps I took:

1. Configure Cluster Resource Manager timer to periodically check balancing state to 5s, set balancing threshold for the metric “MemoryUsage” which I defined to be 2 and define Node capacity for this metric to 1200.
   The clustermanifest looks like:
   [Clustermanifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3e3s.png)
2. Create two stateless application: one called “NodeBalancingTestAppWith500” with Defaultload 200, Weight high and instance count 5 and other one called “NodeBalanceTestStatelessService” with static load 400, weight high and instance count 1 then publish both to cluster.
   The ApplicationManifest looks like:
   [ApplicationManifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws0QL.png)

After I publish two apps to cluster, the load in 5 nodes are like 200,200, 600, 200 and 200.
I expect to see the app “NodeBalancingTestAppWith500”  with defaultLoad 200 in node 3 should be moved to another node after the resource manager kicks in. After balancing , should it look like 200,400,400,200,200 something like this?

Could someone tell why node balancing doesn’t work?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no capacity violation considering that you've defined 1200 as Node capacity for a given metric. If you expand Nodes in SF Explorer - what does it show you? Take a look at "Is Capacity Violation" and "Node Remaining Capacity" columns.

Other from that, set up "MetricBalancingThresholds" to be sure that a current ratio (600/200) will suggest SF that your cluster is imbalanced -

> A Balancing Threshold is the main control for triggering rebalancing.
>   The Balancing Threshold for a metric is a ratio. If the load for a
>   metric on the most loaded node divided by the amount of load on the
>   least loaded node exceeds that metric's BalancingThreshold, then the
>   cluster is imbalanced. As a result balancing is triggered the next
>   time the Cluster Resource Manager checks.